# Create madlib in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

How can I implement a madlib feature in a Dash app, allowing users to update specific text areas (and the entire prompt upon clicking a different button) similar to the provided image? The goal is to create a function that takes a sentence with bracketed words or phrases, turns them into textarea boxes, and outputs a result similar to the image, excluding the share/generate buttons. Currently, my implementation turns the bracketed words/phrases into uneditable links.

```
def generate_madlib(sentence):
    words_in_brackets = [word.strip('[]') for word in sentence.split('[') if ']' in word]
    textarea_boxes = [dcc.Textarea(placeholder=word, style={'margin-right': '10px', 'width': str(len(word) * 10) + 'px'}) for word in words_in_brackets]

    for word, text_box in zip(words_in_brackets, textarea_boxes):
        sentence = sentence.replace(f"[{word}]", f"{text_box}")

    return dcc.Markdown(children=sentence, dangerously_allow_html=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two possible obstacles seem to be the choice of `dcc.Markdown` as a containing element and passing string representation of `dcc.Textarea` instead of components themselves.

Could also be better to set width of inputs based on `0` glyph width<sup>[[ch]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#ch)</sup> instead of pixels:

```py
def width(word):
    # ch = width of 0-symbol
    # 2 - extras for the size control 
    return f"{len(word) + 2}ch"
```

You'll also probably need values of those text areas for further processing. So they should be identified with dictionaries in order to be referenced by [pattern-matching](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks) callbacks later:

```py
def textarea(word, index):
    return dcc.Textarea(
        id={'type': 'word', 'id': index},
        style={'width': width(word), 'height': '1em'},
        placeholder=word)
```

Here is some sample (no control for empty tokens of inconsistent brackets) parsing of bracket-containing string to produce a mixed list of children (strings for plain text and `dcc.Textarea` for text in brackets):

```py
OPEN = True
CLOSE = False

BRACKETS = {
    OPEN: "[",
    CLOSE: "]"
}

def parse_sentence(sentence):

    result = []
    start = 0
    component_index = 0
    key = OPEN

    while True:
        split = sentence.find(BRACKETS[key], start)
        if split == -1:
            break

        token = sentence[start:split]
        if key == CLOSE:
            token = textarea(token, component_index)
            component_index += 1
        result.append(token)

        key = not key
        start = split + 1

    if start < len(sentence):
        result.append(sentence[start:])

    return result
```

And finally the source function with `dcc.Markdown` replaced with something simpler:

```py
def generate_madlib(sentence):
    return html.Div(children=parse_sentence(sentence))
```

Result:
[image: Sample image]